# How to find depth in a list descrip a binary tree

Tags: python, binary-tree, python-3.5, depth

For example:

`[[7, 0, 0], [2, 10, 11], [4, 9, 0], [6, 0, 0], [1, 8, 12], [9, 0, 2], [13, 0, 6], [5, 4, 3], [12, 0, 0], [10, 0, 0], [11, 0, 0], [3, 1, 13], [8, 7, 0]] Root=5`

A list contain a sublist that the first value is the node and second value is children on the left and third is the children on the right.`0` means no children on left/right,I want to find the depth of each node and extract nodes in the same depth.

```
p = lable.index(r)    
depth_list = []    
depth = 0    
depth_list.append([r, 0])    
while lable_left_right[p][1] != 0 or lable_left_right[p][2] != 0:    
    depth += 1    
    left = lable_left_right[p][1]    
    right = lable_left_right[p][2]   
    if left == 0 and right != 0:    
        p = right    
        depth_list.append([p, depth])   
        continue   
    if right == 0 and left != 0:   
        p = left   
        depth_list.append([p, depth])   
        continue
    if left != 0 and right != 0:
        p = right
        depth_list.append([p, depth])
        p = left
        depth_list.append([p, depth])    
        continue
```

which `lable` is a list of all the node (in this case,`[7,2,4,6,1,9,13,5,12,10,11,3,8]` and `r` is the root.`lable_left_right`is the given list
I'm stuck if the node has two children but I can only use one `p` to continue the while loop,so I'll lose another children as a node to finish the task.
Is it possible that in the centre of one while loop to start another while loop and continue process the original loop?If not,is there another way to get the depth of all the node?

Comment: I do not immediately get the syntax. What is the semantics of `0` in `[7,0,0]`?

Comment: 0 means no children on left/right

Comment: It's a tree given as a list of ids. Node 5 has two children, nodes 4 and 3. Node 4 has one child, 9 (on the left). etc. That's why the root node is specified separately.

Comment: Make the current depth an argument to the recursive function. Default it to 0, and pass it depth+1 when you recurse. You start at the root, and compute the depth of its left and right nodes as two separate recursive function calls, then return the larger of the two. The way you write the tree doesn't make the slightest difference (assuming you read it correctly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved recursively using the following:

```
tree = [[7, 0, 0], [2, 10, 11], [4, 9, 0], [6, 0, 0], [1, 8, 12], [9, 0, 2], [13, 0, 6], [5, 4, 3], [12, 0, 0], [10, 0, 0], [11, 0, 0], [3, 1, 13], [8, 7, 0]]

def getRootNode():
    centernodes, leftnodes, rightnodes = map(list, zip(*tree))
    for node in centernodes:
        if (node not in leftnodes) and (node not in rightnodes):
            return node

def getLeftNode(n):
    for i in range(len(tree)):
        if tree[i][0] == n:
            return tree[i][1]

def getRightNode(n):
    for i in range(len(tree)):
        if tree[i][0] == n:
            return tree[i][2]

def maxDepth(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        lDepth = maxDepth(getLeftNode(n))
        rDepth = maxDepth(getRightNode(n))
        if (lDepth > rDepth):
            return lDepth+1
        else:
            return rDepth+1

n = getRootNode()
print("Root Node is " + str(n))
depth = maxDepth(n) - 1
print("Max Depth is " + str(depth))
```